# Automated testing of Captcha flow with Yodlee?

Tags: captcha, yodlee

I'm trying to write an automated test that exercises the Captcha MFA flow with Yodlee.  Unfortunately, every query to the Yodlee test bank (Dag Site Captcha) returns a new captcha (which is, basically by definition, impossible for me to solve in my automated test).

Is there some way to force the Yodlee test banks to return the same Captcha every time?

Comment: You can mock response from yodlee to get always the same image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to force Yodlee Test Bank to return same CAPTCHA every time. As Yodlee tries to keep the Test banks to provide more real bank experience this is why it returns new CAPTCHA.